# Keeping track of success of Completable Futures

Tags: java, future, java.util.concurrent

Is there a way to track the status of failures in Completeable Futures?

I have a scenario where I have three futures where the put() can either succeed or throw a RunTime Exception; and I only want two to succeed. In other words, if the first and second put succeeds, I want to cancel the third and don't want that future to complete. However, if the first one fails, I want to go ahead with the other two.

How do I keep track of exceptions in a CompletableFuture and how can I cancel one future in a set of Futures based on number of successes?

```
 final CompletableFuture<Try<Void>> a = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> put());                                                          
 final CompletableFuture<Try<Void>> b = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> put());  
 final CompletableFuture<Try<Void>> c = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> put());  
    CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture  = CompletableFuture.allOf(a,b,c);
    combinedFuture.get();
```

Comment: possibly 1) call backs or 2) poll

Comment: can you describe this a little more?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not a pro in this corner of Java, so I will leave a detailed answer to those who are.

Answer (score 0):

I think a [Phaser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) will be useful here:

```
Phaser phaser = new Phaser(2);

final CompletableFuture<Void> a =
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { put(); phaser.arrive(); return null; });
final CompletableFuture<Void> b =
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { put(); phaser.arrive(); return null; });
final CompletableFuture<Void> c =
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> { put(); phaser.arrive(); return null; });

CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture  = CompletableFuture.allOf(a,b,c);

phaser.awaitAdvanceInterruptibly(0);
```

`new Phaser(2)` means the Phaser will wait for two `arrive()` calls before marking itself “terminated,” which will cause any methods awaiting advancement to return.